# android - design custom keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard

I want know what is the best way to design keyboard like this

> First Problem

I face in positioning (Del , Clear ) buttons

I design linearlayour(vertical) with weightsum 2 , 
each button 1 but they dont full the whole view

> Second Problem

Del function , I need to delete the character before cursor , when Edittext be empty move to previous EditText

thank you

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/voucherrelative"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/vouchertxt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Enter Voucher Code"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout22"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/codeLinear"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/scanqr"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/roundedwhite"
            android:text="Scan "
            android:textColor="#191919" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttoncheck"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
            android:text="Check"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"

            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/codeLinear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/vouchertxt"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <EditText
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:id="@+id/code1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLength="3"
            android:textSize="25dp" />


        <EditText
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:id="@+id/code2"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLength="3"
            android:textSize="25dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/code3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="3"
            android:textSize="25dp" />

    </LinearLayout>




      <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout22"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="3">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button7"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
                    android:text="7"

                    android:textColor="#ffffff"

                    />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button8"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/codeLinear"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
                    android:text="8"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button9"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button9"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button9"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/codeLinear"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
                    android:text="9"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"

                    />


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="3">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button4"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
                    android:text="4"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button5"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/codeLinear"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
                    android:text="5"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button6"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button9"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button9"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/codeLinear"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
                    android:text="6"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"

                    />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout3"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="3">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/codeLinear"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
                    android:text="2"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/codeLinear"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
                    android:text="3"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"


                    />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout4"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="3"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout3"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/linearLayout3">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button0"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn55"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
                    android:text="."
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
                android:weightSum="4"
                >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonclear"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonDel"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="6.73"
                    android:background="@drawable/roundedwhite"
                    android:text="Clear"
                    android:textColor="#191919"

                    />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonDel"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/roundedwhite"
                    android:text="Del"
                    android:layout_weight="2"

                    android:textColor="#191919"
                     />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Screen shot from my device

[image]

[image]

Comment: use gridLayout in android use row span and colspan feature to solve your issue it will reduce your work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theres a lot if issues with your layout.
Its gigantic! u should use  to make it more object oriented, and easier to read/change.
Your layout could be really just LinearLayout, there is no need for RelativeLayout. 
Just about the numbers - It should be a linearlayout with horizontal orientation with 2 children - numbers layout & del/clear buttons. The layout will be of wieght 4 with the del/clear of weight 3 and the buttons of wieght 1.
the numbers is a linearlayout with vertical orientation with 4 layout that are practicly the same. with weight that divide the layout to three, equally.
The del/clear layout will be divided equally to two.
This should do the trick and will make much simplier.

If u dont know how to use  tag then u should read [this](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)

Comment: Sorry i cant give XML, im not near a computer.